# How to write a function that takes a folder name as argument and return a list of all file names using python and os module?

Tags: python

How to write a function that takes a folder name as an argument and returns a list of all file names using python and `os` module?

```
def dir():
    path = os.getcwd()
    files = os.listdir(path)
    return files
print(dir())
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation, as suggested when you created this account. [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) applies here. We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately specify the problem. We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you specified.  StackOverflow is not a design, coding, research, or tutorial resource.

Comment: I think that code does what you want, except it should take `path` as an argument instead of assuming the current directory.

Comment: It needs `import os` as well.

Comment: why don't you just use os.listdir? you're making a wrapper around a function that already does what you want

Answer (score 0):

you can just use os.listdir , it already does what youre trying to do

```
from os import listdir as Dir

path = 'some/directory'

files = Dir(path)
```

Comment: This overwrites the built in `dir` and should be avoided.